# I have a problem using a speech recognition plugin, how can I fix it?

Tags: flutter

I am developing an application that has speech recognition. It is working perfectly, recognizes the words. However an error is appearing, when the person says nothing, I tried to deal with a timer, not to go null, but the error persists.

This error is appearing:

```
I/flutter (25838): _platformCallHandler call speech.onSpeech
D/SpeechRecognitionPlugin(25838): onError : 7
I/flutter (25838): _platformCallHandler call speech.onSpeechAvailability false
I/flutter (25838): _platformCallHandler call speech.onError 7
I/flutter (25838): Unknowm method speech.onError
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably your application doesn't have a permission for using a microphone. Can you check it in the phone settings: Application --> Permission --> Microphone.

Answer (score -1):

From the data, you Provided I suggest that the speech is not available. Check for the Speech Recognition is available to you if not make it Available in case
As per the documentation https://pub.dev/packages/speech_recognition
Check this value _speechRecognitionAvailable, if false make it true for recognizing the speech Recognition